# We have div's list of the same classes. I want remove one of those which has element with the special class

Tags: jquery

I want to remove `<div class="chrg-item>`who has image whit this class`.gr`
but this code not work!!

```
$('.chrg-item').hasClass('.gr').remove()

<div class="chrg-item">
<img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="chrg-item">
<img class="gr" src="images/thumbs/1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="chrg-item">
<img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the code below:

```
$('.gr').closest('.chrg-item').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check below snippet.

```js
$('.chrg-item').each(function(){
  if($(this).find('img').hasClass('gr')){
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chrg-item">
  <img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="chrg-item">
  <img class="gr" src="images/thumbs/1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="chrg-item">
  <img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for answer
but this code remove image i want to remove div